# PDFBox: Giving Loop within object COSObject{2, 0}

Tags: java, merge, pdfbox

I am using Apache PDFBox to merge different PDF files into one big file. It has been working fine. But recently for one particular file, i have started receiving the below error.

```
java.io.IOException: Loop within object COSObject{2, 0}
    at org.apache.pdfbox.multipdf.PDFCloneUtility.checkForRecursion(PDFCloneUtility.java:277)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.multipdf.PDFCloneUtility.cloneForNewDocument(PDFCloneUtility.java:149)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.multipdf.PDFCloneUtility.cloneForNewDocument(PDFCloneUtility.java:109)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.multipdf.PDFCloneUtility.cloneForNewDocument(PDFCloneUtility.java:119)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.multipdf.PDFCloneUtility.cloneForNewDocument(PDFCloneUtility.java:150)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.multipdf.PDFCloneUtility.cloneForNewDocument(PDFCloneUtility.java:109)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.multipdf.PDFCloneUtility.cloneForNewDocument(PDFCloneUtility.java:119)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.multipdf.PDFCloneUtility.cloneForNewDocument(PDFCloneUtility.java:150)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.multipdf.PDFCloneUtility.cloneForNewDocument(PDFCloneUtility.java:109)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.multipdf.PDFCloneUtility.cloneForNewDocument(PDFCloneUtility.java:150)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.multipdf.PDFMergerUtility.appendDocument(PDFMergerUtility.java:800)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.multipdf.PDFMergerUtility.legacyMergeDocuments(PDFMergerUtility.java:459)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.multipdf.PDFMergerUtility.mergeDocuments(PDFMergerUtility.java:346)
    at
```

Does anyone has any idea why this might be happening or how to fix this error?

I'm using 2.0.26 version of PDFBox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is related to a self-reference within an object (shouldn't be!). It was first fixed in [PDFBOX-5372](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-5372) in the way that you're experiencing (IOException), and the fix was improved in [PDFBOX-5429](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-5429) which no longer throws an exception. This will be in 2.0.27 and a snapshot is available [here](https://repository.apache.org/content/groups/snapshots/org/apache/pdfbox/pdfbox-app/2.0.27-SNAPSHOT/).

Comment: Thanks. Looking for forward for this release.

Comment: *"This is related to a self-reference within an object (shouldn't be!)."* - Well, strictly speaking such references are not forbidden, merely usually useless.